# What exactly is Nx.dev?

Tags: nrwl-nx

What exactly is Nx? I am pitching Nx setup for a work project because I see a great value in it, but I can not explain to my coworkers what is Nx. They ask: if we will add Nx to our Angular project what it will do? Can someone help me to answer this question in a simple way?

Answer (score 5):

As the website states,

> "Nx is a set of extensible dev tools for monorepos, which helps you develop like Google, Facebook, and Microsoft."

In other words, it is a set of helpers that makes developing apps and libraries in a monorepo easier to setup, maintain and work with.

It provides an opinionated (and imo well designed) way of structuring your monorepo. And it comes with some nifty schematics that make it easy to build new apps, libraries, modules, components, etc.

**The winning features for me are**

- built in support for a lot of great libraries that you might want to use, like NgRx for state management, Jest and Cypress for testing, Prettier, etc.
- schematics
- the predefined npm scripts
- ability to easily and automatically build a dependency graph (at least when you're working with Angular). See [Nx wiki](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/wiki/Nx-and-Angular-CLI)
- ability to have frontend and backend code in a monorepo using Nest.js (great for Angular Universal apps), see [nestjs/ng-universal](https://github.com/nestjs/ng-universal)

That's my personal biggest pro's that I mention when I'm trying to convince a client to go for Nrwl Nx.

**As for your co-workers question "what will it do?"**

It will give you an extended set of tools for building your apps and libraries and a guideline for how to structure your monorepo. Still, you and the team will have to agree on the specifics of how you want to structure and organize your projects. And most importantly - stick to it then ;)

Answer (score 1):

> I am pitching Nx setup for a work project because I see a great value in it, but I can not explain to my coworkers what is Nx

First, this is a bit of a juxtaposed statement: how do you see value in something that you don't understand. A small piece of advice, but don't pitch something, as having value, if you can't explain it: this absolutely drives me crazy when junior (and senior) engineers do this.

> Nx is a set of extensible dev tools for monorepos, which helps you develop like Google, Facebook, and Microsoft.

Second, I don't blame you: I couldn't figure out what it is either, but it does put effort into sounding impressive; typically, boring and unambiguous hold greater value than flashy. The problem, with statements like the above, is that the world needs VWs a lot more than Ferraris.